# Duplicate quote on reload last quote

Tags: magento2, quote, programmatically, duplicate

Recently, I needed to create an order programmaticaly.

Here's my code :

```
    public function createMageOrder($orderData) {
        $store=$this->_storeManager->getStore();
        $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer=$this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);// load customet by email address
//        if(!$customer->getEntityId()){
//            //If not avilable then create this customer
//            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
//                ->setStore($store)
//                ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
//                ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
//                ->setEmail($orderData['email'])
//                ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
//            $customer->save();
//        }
        $quote=$this->quote->create(); //Create object of quote
        $quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote
        $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer

        //add items in quote
        foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
            $product = $this->getProduct($item['product_id']);
//            $product->setPrice($item['price']);
            $product->setPrice(0);
            $quote->addProduct(
                $product,
                intval($item['qty'])
            );
        }

        //Set Address to quote
        $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);

        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method

        $shippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                        ->collectShippingRates()
                        ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); //shipping method
        $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method
        $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory

            $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
//        $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready

            // Set Sales Order Payment
            $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);

            // Collect Totals & Save Quote
            $quote->collectTotals();
            $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);

            // Create Order From Quote
            $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);

            $order->setEmailSent(0);
            $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
            if($order->getEntityId()){
                $result['order_id']= $order->getRealOrderId();
            }else{
                $result=['error'=>1,'msg'=>'Your custom message'];
            }
            return $result;
```

This code is perfecty working, the quote is well created.

Now, I need to load items from the last created quote and then fill the cart with this items.

To do this, I tried this :

```
$customerId  = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
                $collection = $this->collection->create();
                $collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId);
                $collection->addOrder('customer_id');
                $quoteId = $collection->getLastItem()->getData('entity_id'); //get id of last quote
                $quote = $this->_quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
                if ($quoteId) {
                    try {
                        $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null);
                        $this->_quoteRepository->save($quote);
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    }
                    $this->_checkoutsession->replaceQuote($quote);
                }
```

This is almost working. If a choose to create a "regular" quote (thanks to my first function), it's working. But if I reload the last quote and then create a quote, the quote is creating twice, the first is an error (it has no item, quantity...) and the second is good.

[image]

Does anyone ever face this issue ?

Comment: I had the same issue with similliar scenario